# What is the "done" function/meaning in the bash while loop?

Tags: linux, bash

I am a new guy for bash shell. I am confused by the below script.

```
#!/bin/bash

input=name.csv

while IFS=',' read -r Family_name First_name

do

 echo $Family_name
 echo $First_name

done < $input
```

Intuitively, I thought the `done` is some kind of boundary marker that told you the `while` field is over.

Here it shows that `done` can take data from a variable. so what is the meaning/function of `done` in the `while` loop?  Thanks.

Comment: Behold the [*syntax of the `while` loop*](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Intuitively, I thought the done is some kind of boundary maker that told you the while field is over.

Correct; `done` ends a while-loop (or for-loop or similar).

> Here it show that done can take the data from a variable.

No; the `< $input` (meaning `< name.csv`) is a [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) being applied to the whole while-loop. So it's the while-loop as a whole, not the `done` specifically, that takes input from name.csv.

Comment: Note that the same redirection syntax applies to other complex commands, e.g. `if ... then ... fi <name.csv`, `{ ... } <name.csv`, and `( ... ) <name.csv`

Comment: if you have a bit of time, can you detail what `< $inputè is ? how can a while loop gets the redirection? the page you mentioned is very technical and hard to read

Comment: @MarineGalantin: From my standpoint as someone who uses Bash, it just means that, for the duration of the while loop, standard input will point to `$input` (e.g. `name.csv`) rather than to whatever it was before. I don't know exactly what Bash does under-the-covers to make this work.

Comment: Since 15 minutes I was working on that and I read this equivalent snippet that makes the script way more comprehensible. Apparently, the code above is strictly equivalent to:   

`#!/bin/bash; input=name.csv; {while ... done} < $input` 

Sorry a bit hard to write a whole script in comment. In other words, the `{ ... }` wraps the commands.

Answer (score 1):

> Intuitively, I thought the done is some kind of boundary maker that told you the while field is over.

That's true. `done` is certainly a part of the while loop itself. The syntax is:

```
   while list-1; do list-2; done
```

> Here it show that done can take the data from a variable

The [input redirection `<`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#REDIRECTION) is *not* specific to `done` keyword alone; rather it's for the entire loop and thus any input read from any statements from `list-1` or `list-2` would read from the file `$input`.

Answer (score -1):

In my little understanding, > in bash means to write to a file while < means to read from a file so basically you are basically telling the loop command to read from the input variable which its value is name.csv

Comment: I am not sure it is as simple as this :)